# Want to Disable HardBack button of android using cordova/android

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to disable hardback button on android using Cordova or android I try to put a code in android as well as android but in android, code created by Cordova there is the only main activity and it disables back button on my 1st page that is login page on other pages on click of back button it exits the app or close the app I want it to disable throughout the application

this is the android main activity code:-

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
//             appView.loadUrl("javascript: onBackKeyDown()");
//            Log.d("logcat", "--------------click click-----------------------------");
//            super.onBackPressed();
//            return true;
//        }
//        return (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ? true : super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
        return true;
    }
```

on Cordova onDeviceReady :-

document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
    console.log("back keypressed")
    return false;
}
```

but this code run on Cordova but still app closed

Answer (score 0):

Just `override` the `onBackPressed` and comment the `super` call and  do not return anything.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
   // super.onBackPressed()
}
```

and Remove `public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` code from your activity.

Thats it.

Comment: not working this works only for 1st-page MainPage as Cordova build code with only mainActivity other pages app close on hit back button